# Syntax highlighting for Rust destroys correct indent level

Tags: bug

While writing a [question](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/3189/2116) I noticed, that it seems to be impossible to get the indenting right.

The following screenshot shows, that the indent of the single `$a` is wrong, although it had been right in the source code of the question.

> [image: Rust indent bug]

Comment: Relevant MSE post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358163/391137

Comment: Weird, but seems like using a code fence with three backticks works correctly, while a code fence with tildas does not. [Screenshot of comparing the two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjbB9.png)

Comment: Given the error report that the bug requires two `$` symbols in the code, I assume this is caused by some kind of interaction with the MathJax parser.